# FileLimit is not working in primefaces file upload when multiple="true"

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss7.x

I trying to set `fileLimit="4"` in my application in `<p:fileUpload>` to validate when user uploads multiple files but not more than four. But this is not working.

When I checked [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf) for this `multiple=true` scenario, there also not working.  And the most weird thing is when I try to autocomplete in eclipse for the attributes inside `<p:fileUpload>` I don't see any `fileLimit`, `fileLimitMessage` etc. I am using Primefaces 3.5v.Is this a bug in Primefaces file upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, PrimeFaces main showcase site is showcasing current alpha/beta/RC version instead of latest stable version. You can verify this by looking at the version information in the footer of the showcase site. This is indeed confusing. Previously, all PrimeFaces alpha/beta/RC versions were showcased on a different showcase site (called PrimeFaces labs).

In your particular case, the `fileLimit` attribute of `<p:fileUpload>` is indeed added in PrimeFaces 4.0 and [absent](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/fileUpload.html) in 3.5. In order to utilize this attribute, you'd need to upgrade to PrimeFaces 4.0. It's currently only available as a [snapshot](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/4.0-SNAPSHOT/) (note: you're supposed to report all issues directly to them then). The final release is scheduled in a few weeks.

Comment: @BalusC....Thanks.As usaual you are the life saver....Is this snapshot available in Primefaces Maven Repo?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it's available in their repo http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html The "snapshot" link in my answer is also pointing to it.

Comment: @BalusC....I have tried installing `primefaces 4.0` version from that repo. I am able to see the attributes but still `fileLimit` is not validating even though I uploded more than limit and I guess primefaces showcase is deployed with latest version cause I see the same behavior of showcase when I used `Primefaces 4.0`

Comment: As said, it's still alpha. If you think it's a bug, report it to them. https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/